# Book where a boy awakes alone from stasis on a spaceship

Tags: story-identification, books

There is a book about a boy who awoke in a spaceship from stasis, found that there was nobody there and all the toy animals crumble into dust when touched, and became friends with a robot. Later, he took lessons in lots of stuff, had his mind integrated with the ship, had the ship modified into a smaller version of itself, and chucked the robot away. In the end, he landed on a planet and tried to get its inhabitants to wire him back to his body, but nobody on the planet understood him (they said something about the old tongue). He overheated the ship in the end and died.

Comment: Roughly when did you read the book? What language was it in? Did it seem to be geared towards any particular age group/audience? Do you have any memories of the cover?